# How to change background color of modal-dialog on Google Apps Script UI built with GUI?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, styling

I'm trying to change the background color of the modal-popup in a google SpreadsheetApp built with on GUI.  .setStyleAttribute() does not seem to work here.  I've also tried to set the style after the GUI component is loaded - no dice.

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight("400") // - works fine, height of modal-dialog is pushed by UiApp height
.setStyleAttribute("background", "black"); // works for Ui element - not for outermost modal-dialog 
  //load the GUI component
  app.add(app.loadComponent("GradeChallengesGUI"));
```

Perhaps it is not possible to change the background of the modal-dialog?  Elements nested underneath are easily modified.  I just can't get to the top parent of the UI. At this point, I'm assuming this isn't possible?

Comment: Actually, .setStyleAttribute() does not seem to work at all with the GUI builder.

Answer (score 0):

Could add everything to a panel type, set bg of the panel, add it to the app.

Answer (score 0):

As you're loading the UI you've created in GUI Builder you can set the background color right there. Choose the top component and set the background color property.

If you prefer code you can do something like this:

`app.getElementById("Component1").setStyleAttribute("background", "black");`

"Component1" is a default ID for the first top element in GUI Builder.

Comment: I tried it too but without success... I had an error message with setStyleAttribute

Comment: Thanks for some clarification, guys, but I'm actually trying to style the default border around UI, which I believe is not possible.  The only access to that area is allowed when you set the title of UI.  At this point, I believe the styling is not allowed.